# Mysql GROUP BY really slow on a view

Tags: mysql, optimization, indexing, view

I have these tables.

```
CREATE TABLE `movements` (
  `movementId` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `movementType` tinyint(3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `movements`
  ADD PRIMARY KEY (`movementId`),
  ADD KEY `movementType` (`movementType`) USING BTREE,
  ADD KEY `deleted` (`deleted`),
  ADD KEY `movementId` (`movementId`,`deleted`);

CREATE TABLE `movements_items` (
  `movementId` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `itemId` mediumint(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `qty` decimal(10,3) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

ALTER TABLE `movements_items`
  ADD KEY `movementId` (`movementId`),
  ADD KEY `itemId` (`itemId`),
  ADD KEY `movementId_2` (`movementId`,`itemId`);
```

and this view called "movements_items_view".

```
SELECT 
movements_items.itemId, movements_items.qty,
movements.movementId, movements.movementType
FROM movements_items
JOIN movements ON (movements.movementId=movements_items.movementId
                    AND movements.deleted=0)
```

The first table has 5913 rows, the second one has 144992.

The view is very fast, it loads 20 result in PhpMyAdmin in 0.0011s but as soon as I ask for a GROUP BY on it (I need it to do statistics with SUM()) es:

```
SELECT * FROM movements_items_view GROUP BY itemId LIMIT 0,20
```

time jumps to 0.2s or more and it causes "Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort" on movements join.
Any help appreciated, thanks.

EDIT:

I also run via phpMyAdmin this query to try to not use the view:

```
SELECT movements.movementId, movements.movementType, movements_items.qty 
    FROM movements_items
    JOIN movements ON movements.movementId=movements_items.movementId
    GROUP BY itemId LIMIT 0,20
```

And the performance is the same.

Edit. Here is the EXPLAIN

```
id  select_type     table               type    possible_keys                    key            key_len     ref                        rows     Extra   
1   SIMPLE          movements           index   PRIMARY,movementid               movement_type  1           NULL                       5913     Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort
1   SIMPLE          movements_items     ref     movementId,itemId,movementId_2   movementId_2   3           movements.movementId       12       Using index
```

Comment: and does the view's select statement, run with an added group by, take the same?

Comment: your select from the view with a group by does read all the records; that doesn't seem comparable to whatever you are doing in phpmyadmin that is returning 20 results.

Comment: @ysth The GROUP BY query is run in phpMyAdmin too so it takes 0.2s or more to get 20 result. I’m editing the question, my mistake. Thank you.

Comment: VIEWs in MySQL have extremely limited ability to access their underlying indexes. For this reason, they are, to my mind, pointless

Comment: @Strawberry I understand, but they allow me to save a lot of PHP coding. I also tried to run the "native" query without passing via the view and the performance is the same. Is there anything that I can do to use better indexes or avoiding the GROUP BY?

Comment: Show `explain SELECT movements.movementId, movements.movementType, movements_items.qty FROM movements_items JOIN movements ON movements.movementId=movements_items.movementId GROUP BY itemId`

Comment: You have a `LIMIT` but no `ORDER BY`.  Which 20 do you want to get?

Answer (score 0):

Turn it inside out.  See if this works:

```
SELECT  movementId, m.movementType, mi.qty
    FROM
        ( SELECT  movementId, qty
            FROM  movements_items
            GROUP BY  itemId
            ORDER BY  itemId
            LIMIT  20 
        ) AS mi
    JOIN  movements AS m  USING(movementId)
```

The trick is to do the `LIMIT` sooner.  The original way had all the data being hauled around, not just 20 rows.

In `movements_items`, is no column or combination of columns 'unique'?  If so, make it the `PRIMARY KEY`.

In `movement`, `KEY movementId (movementId,deleted)` is redundant and should be dropped.

In `movement_items`, `KEY movementId (movementId)`  is redundant and should be dropped.